# Подтверждение паролем суперюзера при каждом изменении файлов на Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, permissions, su

В общем в заголовке всё описал - При сохранении изменённого файла просит ввести пароль подтверждающий мои права суперюзера. В данный момент кодю на VSCode, там вылетает сообщение о провале сохранения из-за недостаточных доступов, и предлагает попробовать как superuser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очевидно, это происходит потому, что вы работаете с файлами, которые вам не принадлежат. Ваши файлы должны лежать в директории `~`.

Не нужно пытаться выдавать особые права программам. Просто разберитесь с тем, где у вас какие файлы хранятся и какие на них права доступа выставлены (а не на VSCode).

Answer (score 0):

Запустите Visual Studio Code через sudo (с правами рут) или измените уровень доступа пользователя к папке через chmod

Comment: права к папке указал 777, всё равно не помогло. При открытии VSCode с правами супера не рекоммендуют мне его так открывать

Comment: @ЭльвинАгарагимов надо указать права и к файлам тоже, и владельца поменять на себя